# Using PC keyboard on Mac - how do make Insert key work (vim, etc)

Tags: macos, vim, keyboard

I just switched from Linux on a PC to a new Macbook Pro.  However, I use an external mechanical USB "PC" keyboard (das keyboard professional).

I still use Linux for some things, but in a virtualbox VM, and the 'Insert' key works as expected (for example to go into insert mode in vim, or shift+insert to paste).

However when working natively in OS X, the 'insert' key never does anything - vim completely ignores it which is pretty much the only place I want to be able to use Insert in Mac OS X.

Yes, I can just use 'i' to go to insert mode like normal people, but years and years of muscle memory habits are hard to break, and nerve-wracking.

Is there some driver or 3rd party app I can use to allow OS X to recognize the 'insert' key on my external keyboard and actively do stuff with it, and map that in vim to go to insert mode?

Comment: This is one of the reasons Vi/Vim doesn't use the (shift-)insert key as the  primary method for insert/put and instead uses `i` and `p`. Just look at the [ADM3A keyboard layout](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vi) which vi was designed on. I know it may sound cruel but learning the Vi/Vim defaults is a good thing. You also get some nice symmetry with `i` and `I`; `a` and `A`; `p` and `P` commands. If you haven't already done so I would suggest you look at vimtutor see`:h vimtutor` for details.

Comment: Is there a way to map the insert key on a pc keyboard to "i" in Mac OS X?

Comment: nevermind, I have hacked around the problem with the app 'Karabiner' by binding Insert (recognized as 'help' in OSX) to 'i' :<item>
 <name>Change help to i</name>
 <identifier>private.map_help_to_i</identifier>
 <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::HELP, KeyCode::I</autogen>

</item>